# Android / iOS sockets - Bad state: Stream has already been listened to flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, sockets

I need to retrieving file data from Camera device(IOT) by using flutter TCP socket.  I I had connected with different ports like command and data ports.Initially socket connected with command port and it received to give some response then disconnecting command port and Reconnecting with Data port and it shows error of "**Bad state: Stream has already been listened to**". My sample code as below, Please suggest how to get file from camera via flutter tcp sockets?

```
 while (k <= attempts) {
  try {
    server = await Socket.connect(_ipAddress, _portAddress,
        timeout: new Duration(milliseconds: timeOut));
    break;
  } catch (Exception) {
    
  }
  k++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not add multiple listeners to your regular-stream. You should convert your stream to a **BroadcastStream**.

So, all You've needed to do is replace `StreamController<>();` with `StreamController<>.broadcast();`

Comment: Thanks Nijat, Please explain how to convert my socket stream to BroadcastStream and How to initialise StreamController to retrieve my file ? please share any sample reference

Comment: kindly check my below code. and its not working stream listen not being called,
'Stream stream = socket.asBroadcastStream();
      stream.listen((event) {
        print("stream listen called:" + event);
      });'